# How to change height of text area on clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, textarea

I have an automatically expanding text-area. But when clicking send button, text-area is not going   back to original height. I have included a sample code. In the project, its implemented using react. Is there any way to make text area height to "50px" when clicking send button? Thank you

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);

function autosize() {
  var el = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.cssText = 'height:auto; padding:0';
    el.style.cssText = 'height:' + el.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }, 0);
}
```

```css
.textarea {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 6px solid #556677;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid pl-5">
    <div class="row w-70 text-center">
      <textarea rows='1' placeholder='Auto-Expanding Textarea'></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="send-btn" onClick={()=> messageSendHandler()}>send</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `messageSendHandler()` function description attached to your post. Does it clear the textarea field? If so, when it happens, the `keydown` event does not occur, and thus the `autosize()` function is not triggered. So, I can see these 2 ways to choose from:

1. if you'd like to run this `autosize()` function on form submit as well, replace `keydown` event with `input` event — it is more universal and can help with different input types (such as dictation),
2. another option would be to reset the textarea height inside the form submit function (`messageSendHandler()`), similarly to how you do it here:

`el.style.cssText = 'height:' + el.scrollHeight + 'px';`

Also, alternatively, maybe [this CSS-tricks URL](https://css-tricks.com/auto-growing-inputs-textareas/) can give you more inspiration on the topic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, message is sending and text area is clearing, but height is not going back to default.  I tried with input event and is still not working. I think your point 2 is the solution.